# How to create multiple versions of a method in c++?

Tags: c++, default-value, overloading

I have the following problem. I have programmed the following method. With the flag it is set, which version is used.

```
#define version2
void calc(double &x
 #ifdef version2
   , double &dot_x
 #endif){
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     double data[]=[... expensive computation ...];
     x=[... something depending on data...];
     #ifdef version2
       dot_x=[... something depending on data ...];
     #endif
   }
}
```

But now, I need both versions at the same time and I don't want to copy it, because I would have to make changes at the computation of data in both the versions every time.
Is there any possibility (like macro etc) to have both versions implemented in one place? And without if-decisions, which cost time?

Thanks a lot for answers,

kildschrote

Comment: you can extract similar parts into other functions.

Comment: Put common code in separate functions, call common function(s) from overloaded function as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define 2 overloads of your function, one that takes one parameter, one that takes 2:

```
void calc(double &x){...}

void calc(double &x, double &dot_x){...}
```

and factor out the common code. You can then decide (at runtime or at compile time ,via an `#ifdef`) which one of the overloads you want to call.

You can even define only one version, with a default second argument (of pointer type),

```
void calc(double &x, double *dot_x = nullptr){...}
```

and if the second argument is not explicitly specified (i.e. is left `nullptr`), then do the "cheap" computation, if not, do the "expensive" one.

I would avoid macros as much as possible (unless really necessary), as they can make your code less readable and induce nasty side effects.

Comment: Hi thank you! But when I have to check if dot_x is set, I have to add if-conditions at all the positions at the code. Does the compiler optimize that and cancel them out?

Comment: @kildschrote If the compiler has enough information then yes, it will "delete" that branch of the computation. If however it cannot decide (say that it depends on user-input), then it has to performs the check. Therefore, in one given function, I'm pretty sure that all branches `if(dot_x)` will be checked only once if there are no side-effects in between, so you shouldn't worry too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ templates to 'write' both versions of your function:

```
template<typename FUNCTOR>
void calc_impl(double &x, FUNCTOR f){
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
     double data[] = [... expensive computation ...];
     x = [... something depending on data...];
     f(data);
   }
}

namespace NULL_F{
   struct F{
     void operator(double data[]){}
   };
}
namespace OPERATE_F{
   struct F{
     F(double &d_x): dot_x(d_x) {}
     void operator(double data[]) {
       dot_x = [... something depending on data ...];
     }
     double &dot_x;
   };

}


void calc(double &x){
   calc_impl(x, NULL_F::F());
}

void calc(double &x, double &dot_x){
   calc_impl(x, OPERATE_F::F(dot_x));
}
```

The template function `calc_impl` is equivalent to your function with everything included.

The two overloads of `calc` select which version is run, employing one of two functors to either do nothing or write to `dot_x` using `double data[]`.

Comment: Thank you for answering this helps me already a lot! Unfortunately my code is a bit more complicated than I wrote... Instead of one for-loop I have several ones and the data array are actually several variables, which are different the single cases. Is there also a solution without calling extra methods?

Comment: If you have several variables making up the data array, then maybe they could be combined together in a struct to make them easier to pass as a parameter. In my code the compiler would realise that the function call to the functor could be a nop and eliminate the call entirely.